# Using dhcpd hosting web site fedora?

Tags: fedora, httpd, isp, dhcp-server

how do we host a web site for small group located across country on dhcpd ipaddress, we have fedora install server with httpd config on right now we can use that web site only on same network. If we want host a web site like www.askquestion.com and that can be browse from diff network diff isp from cell phone.

if any one has done such magic please share the same with us or give us same solutions where we can host free our web site.

thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question but I think you're looking for a dynamic DNS provider like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/).

From their Website:

> DynDNS Free allows you to create a hostname that points to your home or office IP address, providing an easy-to-remember URL for quick access. We also provide an update mechanism which makes the hostname work with your dynamic IP address.

Just sign up for the service, download [ddclient](http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/unix.html) and configure it with the help of this [howto on dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/using_ddclient_with_dyndns_services.html). Don't forget to configure your router to forward port 80/443 (pr whatever port you need) from your public IP address to your fedora server.